# Limit in power sets

Tags: general-topology, analysis

**Question**:

I want to prove that for a collection of sets $E_k$ of a space $X$ such that $\,\forall k, E_k \subset E_{k-1}$, it follows that $\,\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} E_k = \bigcap\limits_{k=0}^\infty E_k\,.$

**Discussion**:

For this I need a relevant topology on the power set of $X$ to be defined, and prove that the limit in this topology coincides with the intersection.

I am stuck at making progress here before I even get the definitions of the topology on the power set right… (what makes a *collection* of sets open in this topology?)

PS: I know very well I can define lim sups and lim infs of sets so that they satisfy these properties, the question is whether some topology on the power set (ideally, an interesting one) gives rise to these definitions as theorems

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit)

Comment: That’s defining things, I want to know whether that definition arises naturally (as a result) given some topology on the power set

Answer (score 1):

Is your collection of sets indexed by the natural numbers? If so, there is a natural [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit) for the limit. (Here, the lim inf and lim sup coincide so the limit is indeed well-defined).

This isn't a topological definition, but are you hoping for one?

Comment: Yes, I’m afraid the idea is to prove these definitions of lim sup and lim inf you’re quoting coincide with the usual definition of limit when equipping the power set with some topology (ideally, an interesting one)